# Parsing on the value to the wrong area

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have some codes like this. Result 1 works fine, but result 2 displays the input from result 1.

Can someone please help me out?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    exampleResult1();   
    function exampleResult1() {
        $(".exampleResult1 .result").text(
            '<div>' + $(".content").val() + '</div>'
        )
    }
    $(".exampleResult1 input").keyup(exampleResult1);


    exampleResult2();   
    function exampleResult2() {
        $(".exampleResult2 .result").text(
            '<div>' + $(".content").val() + '</div>'
        )
    }
    $(".exampleResult2 input").keyup(exampleResult2);

})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="exampleResult1">
    <p><input type="text" class="content"></p>
    Code: 
    <div class="code">
        <code><div class="result"></div></code>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="exampleResult2">
    <p><input type="text" class="content"></p>
    Code: 
    <div class="code">
        <code><div class="result"></div></code>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Below Code :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.exampleResult2 .content').keyup(function ()
    {
        $('.exampleResult1 .result').text($('.exampleResult1 .content').val());
    });

    $('.exampleResult2 .content').keyup(function ()
    {
        $('.exampleResult2 .result').text($('.exampleResult2 .content').val());
    });
 })
```

**UPDATED**

This is [live Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/Davood/dTbEK/4/)

Comment: Why not `$('.exampleResult2 .content')` and `$('.exampleResult1 .content')`? Seems faster? **edit** [Better jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/dTbEK/2/)

Comment: Yes, i think this is faster than `$('.exampleResult2 .content')`

Comment: With separate arguments is faster?? What if you want to select `.foo .bar .three`? Or `div.foo, div.bar pre`? How would you do that? Why would separate args be faster?

Comment: I'm sorry I added a "result" class in the div. Could you please update your code for me? It's a bit confusing for me atm. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's fine =) The nanosecond it saves really wouldn't bother anyone. If you think your version was more readable, you should still use that IMO.